# How to save image of a histogram?

Tags: image, file, matlab, histogram

I have created a histogram using (hist) function... after that, I need to save created image in a file *.png (jpeg) ?
Using what function can I do this?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a figure as an image you can use the functions [PRINT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) or [SAVEAS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html), or you can use the figure menu option **File -> Save**.

For more information on exporting figures from MATLAB, check out [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f3-140348.html).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use something similar to:

```
print('-f1','-dtiff','file_name');
```

to print the figure 1 (-f1) ... anyway check the help for a best description of print and you will find the right driver (-d option) for the type of file you need and extra options

Comment: Thanks! gnovice: Nonprogrammatic solutions are extremely inconvenient.

Comment: @mcandre: That's a matter of opinion, and I did give programmatic options. Also, for future reference, if you want a user to be notified about your comment, you need to use, for example, "@gnovice" on a post of theirs or a post they commented on.